# Newlines as line breaks instead of new paragraphs

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

When I paste a simple bare text like this

```
set1:  7-mild1_spatial-CV 
set2:  7-mild1_spatial-CV-noStarting 

  var                mean1 mean2 meanDif  pairTtestP set1ge set2gt diffMin diffMax 
1 CV_AUC_1h          0.783 0.777 -0.00584 0.003  **  12     1      -0.0183  0.00132
2 CV_AUC_1h_weighted 0.778 0.772 -0.00607 0.005  **  12     1      -0.0217  0.00187
3 CV_R2_dev          0.234 0.224 -0.00981 0.000 ***  13     0      -0.0182 -0.00154
4 CV_R2_devTsc       0.220 0.210 -0.01042 0.000 ***  13     0      -0.0184 -0.00282
5 CV_R2_LR           0.204 0.196 -0.00844 0.000 ***  13     0      -0.0161 -0.00135
6 CV_R2_LRtsc        0.175 0.167 -0.00812 0.000 ***  13     0      -0.0153 -0.00232
7 CV_R2_avgScore     0.173 0.166 -0.00697 0.000 ***  13     0      -0.0162 -0.00270
```

into my Word 2016, looks like this:

[image]

I.e., Word treats every line of this bare text as new paragraph. I would like it to treat the line as line, so that instead of those paragraph breaks it would insert just line breaks. The desired result should look like this:

[image]

How do I achieve this in Word? It's very simple and intuitive, Word should be able to do that.

Answer (score 2):

> It's very simple and intuitive, Word should be able to do that

Word pastes what it receives from clipboard.

Many programs doesn't have different line- and paragraph breaks, in those programs the same character (e.g. `CR LF` in Windows) is used as "break" which is used in Word as paragraph break, therefore it's copied to Word (and other programs too) as paragraph break.

From programs supporting both type of breaks copy & paste is correct.

As a workaround you can select the text after inserting, than replace paragraph marks (`^p`) to manual line breaks (`^l`)

Comment: *"Why would it replace some characters to something else"* But that's what Word does! Why doesn't he keep line breaks as line breaks? That's the only thing I am asking. (PS: thanks for workaround)

Comment: @Tomas please see my edit